# How to enable --debug-only in LLVM build with cmake?

Tags: c++, debugging, llvm

I am building LLVM with cmake and Ninja build generator as following:

```
cmake path/to/llvm/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=1 -DLLVM_ENABLE_CXX1Y=1 -DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=1 -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86" -G Ninja
```

Now I a am trying to use the `-debug-only=mytype` option of opt to print some debug information about my own passes: using the following in my passes code:

```
define DEBUG_TYPE "mytype"
DEBUG(errs() << "My debug message\n");
```

Running opt as following doesn't generate any output messages:

```
opt < a.bc > /dev/null -mypass -debug-only=mytype
```

According to [LLVM documentation](http://llvm.org/releases/3.9.0/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-debug-macro-and-debug-option):

> For performance reasons, -debug-only is not available in optimized build (--enable-optimized) of LLVM.

I suspect this to be the root of my issue, but I can't find how to turn on/off this option when using cmake to build llvm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is controlled by enabling assertions.
`cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON` is enough to turn it on. If you don't see your debug output, then your code is not executed.

Answer (score 3):

I am adding here a complement answer to my question. As @Joky said, `cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON` must be specified when compiling llvm. Also, because my passes are built *outside* the llvm source tree, assertions must also be enabled when building the passes.